# Borland _qsqXXXX.dbf files, what controls the location, insufficient space error

Tags: bde

Borland _qsqXXXX.dbf files, what controls the location, insufficient space error.  I have cleared the StartIn folder but the system can not create new files.

I have also cleared the Windows Temp folder, the .mem file, PDOX*.*

There must be some other mechanism controlling the counter of XXXX files.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a file a 000000...Mem file in c:\windows\temp. Once I deleted it the problem went away.